# Logging out a user from a different application.. Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I have two separate web applications X & Y deployed on two separate sites.. Y takes care    of credit card processing and X takes care of remaining functionality..

Usecase: If A would like to purchase a subscription, he does following things

(i) A logs into X

(ii) A adds a subscription

(iii) After adding the subscription, he logs into Y and adds his credit card information

(iv) He comes back to X and pays for it..

**Now my question here is, how to manually logout A from Y when he is in X..? In crude terms, how to do a logout of a user from other application?**

I did confiure session invalidation period for Y and I am using logout filter in Y also..

I am using **Spring Security**, Hibernate, Spring, Spring MVC.. in both X & Y..

I have posted here also

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?128741-Logging-out-a-user-from-a-different-application-Spring-Security&p=420136#post420136

Thanks,

Vivekanand Alampally

Answer (score 0):

I'll just rewrite the scenario

1. A logs in X
2. After some process X redirects to Y
3. A logs in to Y
4. After the completion of a process in Y, A should be logged out from Y and redirected  again to X

Now for this in step 4, after the completion of process,you have to get the current user principal from SessionRegistry and expire all the session information of that user and than only redirect to Y.